# Python's construct - .sizeof() for construct depending on its parent

Tags: python, parsing, construct

*This post is about Python's [Construct](https://github.com/construct/construct) library*

**THE CODE**

These are the definitions of my constructs:

```
from construct import *

AttributeHandleValuePair = "attribute_handle_value_pair" / Struct(
    "handle" / Int16ul,
    "value" / Bytes(this._.length - 2)
)

AttReadByTypeResponse = "read_by_type_response" / Struct(
    "length" / Int8ul,  # The size in bytes of each handle/value pair
    "attribute_data_list" / AttributeHandleValuePair[2]
)
```

**THE PROBLEM**

Trying to run the following command:

`AttReadByTypeResponse.sizeof(dict(length=4, attribute_data_list=[dict(handle=1, value=2), dict(handle=3, value=4)])`

I receive the following error:

```
SizeofError: cannot calculate size, key not found in context
    sizeof -> read_by_type_response -> attribute_data_list -> attribute_handle_value_pair -> value
```

**WHAT I FOUND OUT**

The size of the `value` field for each `attribute_handle_value_pair` is derived from the `length` field of its parent. I think that the `sizeof()` method is trying to calculate the size of `attribute_handle_value_pair` first, while the `length` field of `read_by_type_response` is still undefined, therefore it cannot calculate its size.

I tried changing the the length of the `value` field to a static value and it worked well.

**MY QUESTION**

How can I calculate the `sizeof()` for a construct that is depending of its parent construct?

Should I redesign the way this protocol is modeled? If so then how?

Comment: looks like an issue of circular dependency rather than a parent/ child evaluation. the docs *do* note that cases like that where the construct uses an array of variable size might trigger `SizeofError`  - http://construct.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html#variable-length-fields

Comment: I am the Construct developer. There is no circular dependency. This could should work fine.

Comment: d = Struct(
    "length" / Int8ub,
    "data" / Bytes(this.length),
   )

d.sizeof()
construct.core.SizeofError: cannot calculate size, key not found in context 

Can you please share the code snippet , which fixed SizeofError

Answer (score 2):

This is currently still an issue in Construct 2.9/2.10 (2.8 appears to be fine).

As a workaround, you can compute the size with a given context by summing the size of the subcons and passing in the length directly.

```
sum(sc.sizeof(length=4) for sc in AttReadByTypeResponse.subcons)
```

If you use the new compiled struct feature, you will need to access the original struct using `defersubcon`.

```
compiled_struct = AttReadByTypeResponse.compile()    
sum(sc.sizeof(length=4) for sc in compiled_struct.defersubcon.subcons)
```